# save output of a compiled application to memory instead of hard disk

Tags: c#, .net, memory

I have an application (EXE file). it is running and while running generate some files (jpeg files) on hard disk. we know read and write to hard disk has poor performance.

Is there any solution to force this application to use memory to save its output jpeg files.

If this solution will be under Windows and use C#, it will be ideal.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can do this. The actual implementation depends on a lot of information you haven't included. For example, how are you generating the images? What are you using them for?

Comment: Do you have the source of the EXE ? IF not then this is till possible but rather tough to do...

Comment: i have not source of EXE file. i want to access these images for semi live showing. for example i want to access last 10 image. each image related to a second of time

Comment: then use a ramdisk - see answer from Jon Skeet...

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option is *probably* not a programmatic one - it's just to use a RAM disk such as [RAMDisk](http://memory.dataram.com/products-and-services/software/ramdisk) (there are others available, of course).

That way other processes get to use the results easily, without any messing around.

Comment: and ... is there any programmatic solution. because i cant attach RAM disk to my product

Comment: @Maziar: Well it's hard to give programmatic solutions when you can't change the program...

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have the source for the EXE and you can't/won't use a RAM disk, the next option is to improve the IO performance of your machine:

Use an SSD or a RAID 0 array, or add loads of memory that can be used as a cache.

But without access to the source code for the application, this isn't really a programming question, because the only way you can 'program' a solution is to write your own RAM disk application - and you can't use a RAM disk, so you've said.

Answer (score 1):

IF you really need to make this solution programmatic then you need to dig deep - depending on the application you will have to hook a lot of functions used by the exe...

That is a really tough thing to do and is prone to problems with several things - permissions/rights, antivirus-protections...

Starting points:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/MonitorWindowsFileSystem.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg462968.aspx